# Poulsbo driver on asus eee, natty narwhal

Tags: graphics, resolution, asus

I'm trying to get set my asus eee pc to use the screen resolution supported by my video card without success. The following commands ran fine but the driver doesn't seem to be loaded as I can't select any widescreen resolutions. The only options are 1024x768 or 800x600.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/emgd 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg-emgd emgd-dkms emgd-xorg-conf
sudo emgd-xorg-conf
```

FROM: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

Answer (score 2):

Driver overview

This page details support for the Intel GMA500 "Poulsbo" video hardware in various Ubuntu releases. Unfortunately the support for this hardware is extremely limited on Linux. There are several drivers, but all lacking certain basic features, future and current maintenance or support for things like suspend.

Please reread the wiki it was updated HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo (last edited 2012-03-29 18:27:20 by mikewhatever)

You may have better luck now.

Repository page: https://launchpad.net/~gma500/+archive/emgd-1.8
Instructions for Natty and Oneiric only. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/emgd-1.8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg-emgd emgd-dkms
sudo emgd-xorg-conf
```

reboot for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

BlueXriders information is accurate, but a bit dated.

There is a new open source driver in the linux 3.x kernel, psb_gfx, and the gma500_gfx (git).

These drivers are enabled in Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2, although when you boot you need to re-start X.

The drivers are also enabled in Fedora 17, although again you need to re-start X.

See also :

http://ubuntuforums.com/showthread.php?t=1229345 (scroll down to the last few pages)

And my blog (I made a custom live CD if you want to test the driver, my live CD is now a bit dated ... )

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/ubuntu-gma500-live-cd/